# Angular Bootstrap modal not returning to the parent window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

[image]I have a Angular bootstrap modal. When the user clicks OK on the modal, I call an angular function and the function works and it returns as desired as I can see the screen is refreshed behind the modal but the control is not returned back to the parent

Here is the modal

```
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure?</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"
            data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="acknowledge(details.id)">Ok</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"
            data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the angular function

```
$scope.acknowledge = function(jobId) {
    var jobId = {
        'jobId' : jobId,
        'userID' : $scope.user
    };
    var jobDetail = $resource('modifyJobDetail', jobId);
    $scope.jobInfo = jobDetail.query().$promise.then(function(resp) {
        $scope.refreshJobDetail();
    });
}

$scope.refreshJobDetail = function() {
    var users = $resource('refreshJobDetail');
    $scope.detail = [];
    $scope.userinfo = users.query().$promise.then(function(response) {
        $scope.detail = response;
        return angular.copy($scope.detail); 
    });
}
```

I can see the fields refreshed in my window but the control is not returned to the parent window.

Comment: I removed the data-dismiss and added the $uibModalInstance.close() at the end of my angular function acknowledge() as shown below but didn't work. I have injected 'ui.bootstrap'.. Is there anything I am missing?

$scope.acknowledge = function(jobId) {
  var jobId = {
   'jobId' : jobId,
   'userID' : $scope.user
  };
  var jobDetail = $resource('modifyJobDetail', jobId);
  $scope.jobInfo = jobDetail.query().$promise.then(function(resp) {
   $scope.refreshJobDetail();
  });
  $uibModalInstance.close();
 };

Comment: Check also the version of angular-ui-bootstrap that you are using. Current version is 1.4.8 and the example below use that version which is incompatible with 1.4.7.

Answer (score 0):

I've adapted your code in a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XnqnO4Db9GAf5XpdLplZ?p=preview) but I've stored the promise returned by $uibModal.open() in the controller scope so I can close it when needed:

```
$scope.openModal = function() {
    $scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'my-modal.html',
      size: 'lg',
      scope: $scope,
      resolve: {
        items: function() {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });
  }

...

$scope.modalInstance.close();
```

Comment: The modal is getting closed but I mean that the page is kind of stuck in between and not sure about the reason.. I have added an image to my first post

Comment: Only to better understand, if you add `backdrop: false` to `$uibModal.open()` options the behavior is the same?

Comment: I am using the bootstrap modal below and not the one you have mentioned
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalAttach-{{details.id}}"
          role="dialog">

Comment: This is the code snippet if it might give an idea on the Angular part.
 $scope.saveFile = function(jobID) {
  var formData = new FormData();
  var file = this.myFile;
  var serviceURL = 'saveAttachment';
  fileUpload.uploadFileToURL(file, serviceURL, jobID); // It calls a directive
  $scope.refreshJobDetail(); // It calls another function to refresh the view
 }

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand where is used this code... and what does it has to do with the modal...

Comment: I am sorry to confuse.. The issue is fixed.. I was calling a directive and the issue was the response was not returned properly and it was holding it. I set a proper return statement in my directive and it started working